# How to automatically refresh table view in view controller upon entering screen?

Tags: swift

I'm able to make use of refreshControl and pull down to manually update the screen, but how can i update it automatically every time i enter the screen without having to pull down.

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        configureRefreshControl()
        tableView.refreshControl = refreshControl   
    }

func configureRefreshControl() {
        self.refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleRefreshControl), for: .valueChanged)
        self.refreshControl.tintColor = UIColor.white
    }
    
    @objc func handleRefreshControl() {
        updateCommentsOverview()
    }
```

Comment: What do you want to do exactly upon entering screen ?

Comment: run updateCommentsOverview automatically

Answer (score 1):

You can call tableView.reloadData() or updateCommentsOverview() either on viewDidLoad. Which will update once Per screen launch. Or call it on viewWillAppear. Which will cause an update every-time you “see” the screen, meaning even when you come back from the background.
I can only guess you mean to use viewWillAppear.
See - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621510-viewwillappear for more info